# Javascript confusing Object function "has no method" error

Tags: javascript, function, object

So I have a function which looks like this:

```
function Students(){
  // Function add:
  //  Returns: add page
  this.add = function(){

  // Get template
  $.get('view/students/new.html', function(template){

    // Templating
    var html = Mustache.to_html(template);

    // When document ready, write template to page
    $('document').ready(function(){
      $('#container').html(html);
    });
  });
};

};
```

When I try to call it's `add` function like so:
`Students.add();`

I get the error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Object function Students(){...}has no method 'add'`

What gives?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To use that implementation of `Students`, you should do this:

```
var students = new Students();
students.add();
```

However, that's probably not what you want. You probably meant to define `Students` like this:

```
var Students = {
    add: function() {
         $.get( /* ... */ );
    }
};
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
Students.add();
```

Answer (score 3):

Students is intended to be called as a **constructor**.

```
var s = new Students();
s.add()
```

Inside of `Students`, `this` will be a new object that inherits from Students's prorotype, and is returned automatically.  So saying

```
this.add = function() ....
```

is adding the `add` function onto this object that's being returned.  But the function will be created *de novo* each and every time you invoke this function.  Why not add it to the prototype instead, so the function will exist only **once**, and not have to be needlessly re-created each and every time.

```
Students.prototype.add = function(){
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not adding an "add" function to the "Students" function with that code; you're adding it to *instances* created by using "Students" as a constructor.

```
var student = new Students();

student.add(); // won't get the error
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, `Students` doesn't have an `add` method.

I think you're assuming you know how `this` works. It isn't a reference to the function, unless you manually make it so. The value of `this` will depend entirely on *how* you call `Students`.